# Converting Edgelist to Adjacency List

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-list

I have an object that shows me the connection between the indexes and that has variables `index1`,`index2`. Based on the connection of the indexes I would like to create a tree, that would always start from `0`.

In this example the `0` is connected with `2` and `5` so they would be added to the tree first, then continuing from the lowest, I would need to find what numbers are connected to `2`, which in this case are `6` and `7`, etc..

```
{index1=0, index2=2}
{index1=3, index2=4}
{index1=1, index2=4}
{index1=0, index2=5}
{index1=2, index2=6}
{index1=1, index2=5}
{index1=2, index2=7}


               0
          2       5
       6    7       1
                      4
```

It seems like what I need is to convert it to Adjacency list.

As a final result I need to `preorder traverse` through the tree or all of the nodes and get a result, which in this case would be:

```
0 - 2 - 6 - 7 - 5 - 1 - 4
```

What should I use to get the desired result?

Or how can I create a `Adjacency List`, where I could add to the root, meaning that if I were to give values `(0, 2)` and then `(0,5)` it would add those values not under eachother but separately and then `(2, 6)` would go under the `node` 2.

Comment: Just a hint for you, your tree node will need to have a member variable that represents the list of child nodes, in this case, it is simply an arraylist.

Comment: @Mox i tried, but I dont really understand what you mean

Comment: It is called an adjacency list. google that =)

Comment: in fact your question can be rephrased as "how do I convert edgelist to adjacency list".

Comment: @Mox will change it, adjacency list looks the thing I need.

Comment: You could create a recursive function to loop through the parent and child node, then get the adjacency list, please refer to [here](https://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/tree/tree6.php) and [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2084484.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os

vertexNum =#Vertexes
edgeNum = #Edges
edgeList = [[0,[-3]]]

source = "destination of edgelist file"

f = open(source, "r")
l = f.readlines()
l2 = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in l]

for i in range(1,vertexNum+1):
    edgeList.append([i,[]])

for line in l2:
    graph_Local = [line.split(" ")[0],line.split(" ")[1]]
    edgeList[int(graph_Local[0])][1].append(int(graph_Local[1]))
    edgeList[int(graph_Local[1])][1].append(int(graph_Local[0]))


with open('destination to save adjacency list','w') as eFile:
    for item in edgeList:
        eFile.write("%s\n" % item[1])

eFile.close()
```

Comment: Try to add some description with your code. What your code does ? how it solve the problem ?

Comment: It is a python code.
Load a graph from edge list file and then converting the loaded graph into the adjacency list. Finally, the new formed graph is saved into a file.

Answer (score 0):

Not so optimized but i think it will work.

```
static class Connection{
  int index1;
  int index2;
  Connection(int index1,int index2){
       this.index1=index1;
       this.index2=index2;
  }
}

private static List<Connection> connections;
private static List<List<Integer>> adjList;
private static int max;

static void makeAdjList(){
     for(int i=0;i<max;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<connections.size();j++){
            Connection c=connection.get(j);
            if(c.index1==0||c.index2==0){
               adjList.get(i).add(c.index1==0?c.index2:index1);
            }
        }
     }
}
```